# BARPLOT in R and proportions

Tags: r, bar-chart

The question i have to solve is this

> "Using the simple graphing functions in R, create a bar chart
>   displaying the proportion of gun unsolved homicides by year, from 1980
>   to 2015. Describe any trends you see."

First to create the Barplot, i create a subset of the data to only select unsolved mysteries from the large data set which works fine.

```
unsolvedCASES<-subset(dataset,Crime.Solved =="No")
```

`dput(head(unsolvedCASES, 20))`
But when i go to make a basic barplot using the function below the whole plot is black

```
barplot(dataset$Crime.Solved == "No", 
        main = "Unsolved Homicides by Year, from 1980 to 2015",
        xlab = "Year 1980-2015", ylab = "Number of Homicides", 
        names.arg = dataset$Year, col = rainbow(3))
```

or even

```
  barplot(unsolvedCASES$Year)
```

my first question is how do i make this bar plot show the number of unsolved cases per year AND THEN how do i show its proportions?

I was given a hint for the proportions saying

> "This proportion is also known as the percentage of unsolved homicides
>   for any specific year, and is easily obtained by dividing the number
>   of unsolved homicides that year by the total number of homicides that
>   year"

if that helps.

your help is greatly appreciated !!!
THANKS!!

C:\Users\erinl\Downloads\Homicides .htm

Comment: Please do your homework. Also you might want to give sample data using `dput(df)` and what you have tried.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(unsolvedCASES)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(unsolvedCASES, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas i posted the html doc at the bottom im just super puzzeled as to by its not working

Comment: @NelsonGon im sorry if it seems as if im not doing my homework however i promise you that i am and hence why im asking this question

Comment: The provided link(seems like a path) doesn't work. use `dput(data)` and add that to your question.

Comment: @NelsonGon i added it but there is a ton of data  so idk how it helps thanks for getting back to me so quickly

Comment: Are you strictly using base R?

Comment: @nelson Sadly yes :(

Comment: check my answer. The data is not base R but the method is. Tweak it as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic sample plot created using the `flights` dataset in the `nycflights13` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
flight_subset<-subset(flights,year==2013)

(props<-prop.table(table(flight_subset$year,flight_subset$carrier)))
barplot(props)
```

Here is a sample plot
[image]

EDIT: Based on your comment, you would do something like:

```
flight_subset<-subset(flights,carrier=="UA")
(props<-prop.table(table(flight_subset$year,flight_subset$month),1))
barplot(props,col="dodgerblue")
```

Comment: OMG THIS WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you so much !! can this work for if i wanted to create a bar chart to show the proportion such as dividing the the total of flites each year by a certain type of flight each year year ?

Comment: Check my EDIT. Also please click the tick if the answer worked for you to accept it.

Comment: The data is unfortunately hard to use to illustrate a more specific example.

Comment: Sorry i think i asked the question wrong i made a new question on stackoverflow called Proportions barplot for a certain average within a variable
 so i could explain better if you go to that question you can see my code